# flex+bison in a php extension

Tags: yacc, php-extension, php-internals

I have created a small parser in c using flex and bison. The parser writes the result to some global variables and the caller function reads it from there.

I am trying to package my parser as a php extension. From what i understand from the php documentation true global variables are not recommended because they are not thread-safe and i have to use module globals instead.

In order to use module globals you have to pass in the function TSRMLS_DC as its last argument.

To you know if i can modify the yyparse to accept TSRMLS_DC as an argument. Or if there is another way to access global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use global variables, but use a more modern parser generator that is also reentrant. Look for instance how I've done it for the [meta extension](https://github.com/flavius/phpmeta) (I use a slightly changed lemon and re2c).